# Upgrading processor IBM x31

Tags: windows-7, cpu, upgrade, thinkpad

I have an IBM X31 notebook that is running windows 7 home premium. Its current specs are a 1.4GHz intel pentium processor with 1GB of RAM. Is it possible to upgrade the processor in it and if so how and which processr(s) would work with it? Thanx in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a 1.4Ghz [X31](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X31) and I am on my sixth ThinkPad now (a [X200s](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X200s)).  I've taken ThinkPads apart, upgraded them, fixed them, etc., so I can tell you that you definitely cannot upgrade the processor on your X31 - it's soldered to the motherboard.

I also do not think that Windows 7 well run very well on it and XP will work a lot better.  Your X31 will have a XP Professional licence as standard.

You can upgrade the RAM to 2 x 1GB though, which would help a lot.  You can possibly upgrade the motherboard to one from a [X32](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X32), which came with the [Pentium M Dothan](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Pentium_M_(Dothan)) up to 2.0Ghz (the [X31](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X31) came with [Banias](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Pentium_M_(Banias)) chips up to 1.7Ghz, with half the amount of cache).

Answer (score 1):

Running Windows 7 Professional on X31 with 1300MHz Banias CPU. I can tell you it runs well even with only 1GB RAM. Takes 3 seconds to open MS Excel 2010.

I also installed Intel 2200BG miniPCI wireless card. You need to tweak the laptop to accept the wireless card (utility available in the net). Otherwise you'll have to shell out $$$ for an IBM approved wireless card.